# Can arangosh support shebang with --javascript.execute

Tags: arangodb, arangojs

`arangosh` seems not to like having shebangs in javascript files loaded with `--javascript.execute`

I'm making sysadmin tools for our arangodb - tools that the guy with the root password will use when stuff breaks! Tools that wont ask for permission, that will bypass arangodb's permission restrictions. I use a unix socket for that.

So far I have made `/opt/arango-tools/bin/arangojs` with:

```
#!/bin/bash
SOC=/var/lib/arangodb/unrestricted-endpoint
if [ -r $SOC ] && [ -w $SOC ]
then
  /usr/bin/arangosh --server.endpoint unix://$SOC --javascript.execute "$@"
else
  echo Needs R/W to $SOC, consider running with sudo 
  exit 1
fi
```

and then a simple helper tool `/opt/arango-tools/bin/list-users.js` with:

```
#!/opt/arango-tools/bin/arangojs
var users = require("org/arangodb/users");
db._listDatabases().forEach(function(db_name) {
  console.log(db_name);
  db._useDatabase(db_name);
  users.all().forEach(function(row) {
    console.log("  " + row.user + 
      (row.active ? ' (active)':' (disabled)'));
  });
});
```

but then when running it goes like:

```
mogul@guldager:~$ sudo /opt/arango-tools/bin/list-arangodb.js
2016-03-17T08:46:46Z [11876] ERROR JavaScript exception in file '/opt/arango-tools/bin/list-arangodb.js' at 1,1: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
2016-03-17T08:46:46Z [11876] ERROR !#!/opt/arango-tools/bin/arangojs
2016-03-17T08:46:46Z [11876] ERROR !^
mogul@guldager:~$
```

Obviously a line starting with `#!` is not valid javascript.

Suggestions / workarounds / ideas - anyone?

Comment: The feature is available with 2.8.6 via https://arangodb.com/Downloads ; can you mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: The feature is available but not as described.  Should be: javascript.execute-string  string…  Execute JavaScript code from string
Default: []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its currently not possible.

However, we liked the idea, and ArangoDB 2.8.6 onwarnds will be able to do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/arangosh --javascript.execute 
print('hello world')
```

It will for shure source the regular environment so you can do anything with this that

```
/usr/bin/arangosh --javascript.execute /tmp/test.js
```

could do before.